# How to grant root access without SuperSU

Tags: android

I am currently able to get root access in my app on a rooted device using SuperSU. When my app requests root access a dialog from SuperSu is displayed which a user then clicks on "Grant" to allow the permissions.

I want to be able to bypass this step and let my app get root permission programmaticaly without having to click on the "Grant" button on the SuperSu dialog.

How do I go about this?

Comment: hum, isn't because of a very specific reason that the user should explicitly grant that permission?

Comment: Yes, ideally a user should grant that permission. In this case I want the permission to be granted automatically, since SuperSU can do it then my app should be able to do it too right?

Comment: what I mean is, getting that permission automatically might be seen as a malicious move, if the user needs to grant his permission explicitly it's because he should be aware that you're app wants root privileges. or maybe I'm just too suspicious...

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. I did't want to go into the specifics of the business needs, our users and WHY I need to grant it automatically.

The app not publicly distributed (Play store), it is preinstalled on an already rooted device which is then made accessible to users.

This should not be a discussion on WHY I want to grant root access automatically but rather HOW I should go about doing it.

Comment: I was just checking, I think that if you ask for help to do something illegal one should know, that's all. btw I didn't downvote

Comment: @lelloman Its not Illegal, I'm providing a device with the app, then users use the device (which I own). Just to provide more context, when I release the device it already has the app and it has already been granted root access by SuperSu. So what I'm trying to avoid is a case whereby the app might loose the permission and then ask for it again while its out there in the field. The users are not tech savvy and they will not know what the SuperSu dialog is or what to do with it. That's why I want to be able to grant it automatically

Comment: For the guys downvoting, it would be nice to please add a comment why you think this is a bad question.

Comment: if i had the option not to request root access I would be happy to remove it, the functionality that requests it is very minimal and is not part of the functionality being used by the users. There is nothing malicious going on in the background its all just supposed to improve the user's experience.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want to be able to bypass this step and let my app get root permission programmatically without having to click on the "Grant" button on the SuperSu dialog.

You can't. The user must grant your app root access. Unless you build your own SU management app, you can't get around this initial permission request.

> I'm providing a device with the app, then users use the device (which I own). Just to provide more context, when I release the device it already has the app and it has already been granted root access by SuperSu. So what I'm trying to avoid is a case whereby the app might loose the permission and then ask for it again while its out there in the field. The users are not tech savvy and they will not know what the SuperSu dialog is or what to do with it.

If you own the device then you can change the "Default access" to "Grant" in SuperSu settings. You can also change this on a per-app basis.

You mentioned in the comments that your app will already have superuser permissions. You have root access, so you could change SuperSu's shared preferences to have your app always be granted access. Again, you implied that you own the device so you shouldn't need to modify SuperSu preferences programmatically.

If you really needed to modify SuperSu's preferences then the following code should change the app's access settings to always allow and disable notifications (Using [android-shell](https://github.com/jrummyapps/android-shell)):

```
@WorkerThread
public static boolean tryChangingSuperSuDefaultAccess(Context context) throws Exception {
  String packageName = context.getPackageName();
  PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

  // Get the preferences for SuperSu
  Context packageContext = context.createPackageContext("eu.chainfire.supersu", 0);
  SharedPreferences superSuPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(packageContext);
  File superSuPrefsFile = getSharedPreferencesFile(superSuPrefs);

  // Copy SuperSu preferences to our app's shared_prefs directory
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
  File directory = getSharedPreferencesFile(preferences).getParentFile();
  File destination = new File(directory, "eu.chainfire.supersu.xml");
  int uid = pm.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).uid;
  destination.getParentFile().mkdirs();
  Shell.SU.run("cp \"" + superSuPrefsFile + "\" \"" + destination + "\"");
  Shell.SU.run("chmod 0660 \"" + destination + "\"");
  Shell.SU.run("chown " + uid + " " + uid + " \"" + destination + "\"");

  // Now we can edit the shared preferences
  superSuPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("eu.chainfire.supersu", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = superSuPrefs.edit();
  editor.putString(String.format("config_%s_notify", packageName), "no"); // disable SuperSu notifications
  editor.putString(String.format("config_%s_access", packageName), "grant"); // Set access to grant for this app
  // noinspection all
  editor.commit();

  // Copy the edited shared preferences back
  return Shell.SU.run("cp \"" + destination + "\" \"" + superSuPrefsFile + "\"").isSuccessful();
}

private static File getSharedPreferencesFile(SharedPreferences preferences)
    throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
  Field field = preferences.getClass().getDeclaredField("mFile");
  if (!field.isAccessible()) field.setAccessible(true);
  return (File) field.get(preferences);
}
```

I would not recommend using the code above. You should be transparent and educate your users. If you own the device, as you claimed, you can change these settings yourself using the app.

Comment: But how does SuperSU get root access? Couldn't the app use the same mechanism?

Comment: I'd like to know as well. The problem for us is that the SuperSu configuration doesn't persist between factory resets. We also supply purpose-designed appliances based on off-the-shelf Android tablets (with a different launcher so that it's a single app only)